# To create dynamic ngModel in angular 6+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hi I am creating a table in which rows changes based on certain conditions.

```
<table id="totBudget">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>CC_1</th>
          <th>CC_2</th>
          <th>CC_3</th>
          <th>CC_4</th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>CC_NAME</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of source; let i= index">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="{{item.value}}1" id="{{item.value}}1"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="{{item.value}}2" id="{{item.value}}2"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="{{item.value}}3" id="{{item.value}}3"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="{{item.value}}4" id="{{item.value}}4"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="{{item.value}}tot" id="{{item.value}}tot"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="{{item.value}}cc" id="{{item.value}}cc"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I need to create a dynamic ngModel whose name will be same as id mentioned in the row example: {{item.value}}1.
Here I am not sure how to create ngModel for all inputs whose name depends on item.value and table row.
Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create object that will hold the state of the table like this

TS:

```js
tableObject ={}
```

HTML:

```html
        <tr *ngFor="let item of source; let i= index">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" [(model)]="tableObject[item.value +'1']" class="{{item.value}}1" id="{{item.value}}1"></td>
          <td><input type="text" [(model)]="tableObject[item.value +'2']" class="{{item.value}}2" id="{{item.value}}2"></td>
...
        </tr>
```

Let me know it that helped you

Comment: @RKD, your welcome, can you mark as the right answer, and upvote, so other people that looking will also have a solution?